# Security with Kernel IP Forwarding Enabled

Tags: debian, security, firewall

I recently enabled IP Forwarding on a production web server that also acts as a VPN server.  What, if any, security issues did I just set myself up for?  And are there any iptables rules I should set up to limit forwarding to my VPN tunnel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only have security issues if your server gets compromised. Anyone/thing that gets into your server will have access to machines on your network, as if it was the server (your machines probably trust your server). You should definitely have *some* iptables rules! Basically you want iptables to block everything from the outside world to your firewall, except your webserver port(s) and VPN server port(s).

I would recommend something like shorewall http://www.shorewall.net/ to set this up for you, but some people think coming up with the iptables rules yourself if better since you'll understand more about what's going on.

Comment: I must say that the sentence *"You will only have security issues if your server gets compromised."* looks funny :)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely minimize any routing-capability of that server by using iptables (FORWARD).

Which VPN-server do you run? Do you have fixed addresses for your VPN-accounts?
I suppose you have basic knowledge how iptables should be called (what option/argument does what)?

Some example-rules might look like that, you have to replace XXXX and variables with sensible values fitting your setup:

```
IPT=/usr/sbin/iptables
# deactivate FORWARD by default as you only want to grant access with a whitelist.
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
# allow established connections
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# allow access to your VPN-server from the outside
$IPT -A INPUT -i $OUTER_INTERFACE -p XXXX --dport XXXX -j ACCEPT
# allow access to some host (-d)/protocol (-p)/destination port (--dport) from one VPN-account
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $VPN_INTERFACE -o $LAN_OR_OUTER_INTERFACE -s $IP_FROM_VPN -d $SOME_HOST -p XXXX --dport XXXX
# allow access from your LAN-network/-host to the VPN-clients
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN_INTERFACE -o $VPN_INTERFACE -s $LAN_NET_OR_HOST -j ACCEPT
# allow access from the VPN to the WAN
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $VPN_INTERFACE -o $OUTER_INTERFACE -s $VPN_NET_OR_HOST -j ACCEPT
```